# Spatial extent in the metadata does not appear

Tags: extents, metadata, geonetwork

The spatial extent never appears in the metadata tab, even if the extent value has been inserted on the map while editing the metadata.

In creating the metadata, I insert the geographical area of perception of the data, drawing it on the map. When I save the metadata and consult it, this information does not appear in the metadata tab, but the spatial extend is empty, such as:
https://geocatalog.cloud.ponmetropalermo.it/geonetwork/srv/ita/catalog.search#/metadata/04802ffb-424c-4ce6-8c01-5d72f58d0ad8

What could be the problem?

Comment: can you show the XML for the spatial extent you've added to the metadata

Comment: What version of GeoNetwork are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.10.4, I also tried with version 3.10.10 but I see the bbox without a background map.

Comment: the issue would appear to be with the background map not the extent, if you see a bounding box.   You could check by looking at the XML view of the metadata